# transfer of information from one function to another through a global variable in angular controler

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller, global-variables

I have a little trouble with passing value from one function to another in one angular controller.

i have event

```
onTimeRangeSelected: function (args) {
          $scope.dayPilotCal.clearSelection();
          $scope.createNewEventModalWindow(args);
      },
```

event call function

```
 $scope.createNewEventModalWindow = function(args)
    {
      console.log('create new event dialog');
      $rootScope.newEvent.start = args.start.value;
      console.log($rootScope.newEvent.start);
      ngDialog.open({
          ......
      });

    }
```

than i handle dialog confirm button click event

```
 <button
      type="button"
      class="ngdialog-button ngdialog-button-primary"
      ng-click="btnCreateEventClicked()"
    >Create</button>
```

and call function

```
$scope.btnCreateEventClicked = function(){
  console.log('btn create event clicked');
  ngDialog.close();

  console.log($rootScope.newEvent.start);
};
```

so that my problem - in first case `console.log($rootScope.newEvent.start);` print to console real date. But in the second function `console.log($rootScope.newEvent.start);` print into console `'undefined'` value.

all code are in the same controller.  And in the first lines of controller i define my global variable `$rootScope.newEvent={};`

Please help me in that problem.

Comment: Can you post your controller and any directives you are using?

Comment: var TimesheetModule = angular.module('TimesheetApp', ['daypilot', 'ngDialog']);

TimesheetModule.controller('TimesheetCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, TimesheetFactory, ngDialog)
  { .......  });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Global variables makes testing the code really difficult. Because any function can have access to the global scope. In your example I would assume their is another part of your coding that changes $rootScope.newEvent.

If this variable has to be globally available I would suggest to use a service.

If their is no need for this var to be globally accessible, than just change $rootScope.newEvent to $scope.newEvent.

Comment: thanks for help. My proplem - that is my global variable  $rootScope.newEvent={};  vas in the controller directly.
and initialization ={}; performed every time I appealed to the controller.